# Swift: present actionsheet and make the background interactable too

Tags: ios, swift, uiactionsheet

I would like to present an action sheet on my app but still make the viewController the action sheet was presented on interact-able. Is this possible?

I've tried presenting the action sheet but clicking on the outside of the action sheet dismisses the action sheet.

Do I need to use custom actionsheet and if so how?

```swift
let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Music", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add to a Playlist", style: .default, handler: nil))
actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Create Playlist", style: .default, handler: nil))
actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Remove from this Playlist", style: .default, handler: nil))

actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: If my understanding is correct. on tap of Viewcontroller you want action sheet should not dismiss

Comment: @channu That is correct